# Acer Aspire 4715 boot error

Tags: boot, acer-aspire, bcdedit

> RECOVERY
>
> Windows has encountered a problem communicating with a device connected to your computer.
>
> This error can be caused by unplugging a removable storage device such as an external USB 
>   drive while the device is in use, or by faulty hardware such as a hard drive or CD-ROM drive 
>   that is failing. Make sure any removable storage is properly connected and then restart your computer
>
> If you continue to receive this error message, contact the hardware manufacturer.
>
> ⠀⠀ File: \Boot\BCD
>
> ⠀⠀ Status: 0xc00000e9
>
> ⠀⠀ Info: An unexpected I/O error has occurred.

That's the error message that is always appearing on my screen every time I open my laptop. I can't open the windows.

Comment: Can you boot if you switch to safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't boot up in safe mode and using windows 7: 
Boot off your windows 7 DVD and select repair my computer in the bottom left of the window. Select startup repair.